# Равенство простых типов и объектов

Tags: java

Можно ли сравнивать значение разных типов, таких как `byte`, `short`, `char`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`?
Иначе говоря, будет ли иметь смысл логическая операция:

```
int x = 6;
byte y = 6;

if(y == x) {
    //Код
}
```

Вопрос возник из-за такой вещи, как совместимость типов. Так же прошу ответить, что случится (если, конечно, случится), если поменять переменные местами в операторе `if`?
Такой же вопрос, но уже с объектами, классы которых находятся в одной ветке наследования:

```
public class Dog {
    //Код класса
}

public class Son_Of_Dog extends Dog {
    //Код
}

public class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Dog d = new Dog;
        Son_Of_Dog s = new Son_Of_Dog();

        if(d.equals(s)) {
            //Код
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для корректной работы сравнения данных разных типов, между ними должна быть возможность неявного преобразования. В частности при сравнении byte и int такая возможность есть. Но вообще я Вам рекомендую самому попробовать поиграть с разными типами, это позволит Вам лучше понять особенности языка и увидеть их в действии. Что касается ссылочных типов, то там при правильной реализации метода equals в Вашем классе порядок сравнения не важен.